# Open street Map How to get coordinates of all cities in a specific country

Tags: web-services, web, openstreetmap

I am using openstreetmap webservices to get longitude and latitude from cities and the opposite 
What I want to add is a simple select button of countries and cities to the wweb user so I can send my request like this:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?country=xxxxx&country=yy&format=xml&accept-language=en-GB

in which "xxxxx" and "yy" is the country and the city selected by the user .
The problem is that I did not find a request that will give me all the cities of the country xxxx at the same time from OSM, so I can minimize the request sent to the OSM service and  parse the response to display all the cities and their data.
So is there a request to make OSM give me all cities or I need to define them in my database or in a script file?

Comment: Did you tried nominatim.osm.org already?

Comment: yes i tried and i had the results i needed but what i want is a to know if there is a request that can give me a list of citys of a given coutry or country code

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a typical task for a geocoder (which [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) is).

You could obtain this information out of OSM's raw [data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) or via the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). But there is no straightforward way for this because in order to know which city belongs to which country you will have to do some post-processing of the data.

I think the best would be to find a database already holding the information you are looking for. Try asking on [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i did find data of what i want but the problem is that sometimes citys written in my database may not be supported by the OSM webservice that's why i wanted their city names not some random data that may complicate my results